# Change Document Library Webpart's Toolbar Type to 'Show Toolbar' programmatically in 'sharepoint online sandbox solution'

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, sandbox-solution

I want to change the Document Library's webpart property **'Toolbar Type**' from **'Full Toolbar' to 'Show Toolbar' programmatically**.

[image]

I am working on `Office 365 sandbox solution`.I am creating document library & it's view programmatically. I have tried following:

```
myView.Toolbar = @"<Toolbar Type='FreeForm'/>"; 

// I am not sure that it is 'FreeForm' or not for 'Show Toolbar'
```

I want to achieve this type of view for my library. I want to **show toolbar on library programmatically.**

[image]

If any other solution is possible to get toolbar on Document Library programmatically then provide here.

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me

```
    private static void SetToolbarType(SPView spView, string toolBarType)
{
    spView.GetType().InvokeMember("EnsureFullBlownXmlDocument",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    null, spView, null, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    PropertyInfo nodeProp = spView.GetType().GetProperty("Node",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    XmlNode node = nodeProp.GetValue(spView, null) as XmlNode;
    XmlNode toolbarNode = node.SelectSingleNode("Toolbar");
    if (toolbarNode != null)
    {
        toolbarNode.Attributes["Type"].Value = toolBarType;
        // If the toolbartype is Freeform (i.e. Summary Toolbar) then we need to manually 
        // add some CAML to get it to work.
        if (String.Compare(toolBarType, "Freeform", true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0)
        {
            string newItemString = "";
            XmlAttribute positionNode = toolbarNode.OwnerDocument.CreateAttribute("Position");
            positionNode.Value = "After";
            toolbarNode.Attributes.Append(positionNode);
            switch (spView.ParentList.BaseTemplate)
            {
                case SPListTemplateType.Announcements:
                    newItemString = "announcement";
                    break;
                case SPListTemplateType.Events:
                    newItemString = "event";
                    break;
                case SPListTemplateType.Tasks:
                    newItemString = "task";
                    break;
                case SPListTemplateType.DiscussionBoard:
                    newItemString = "discussion";
                    break;
                case SPListTemplateType.Links:
                    newItemString = "link";
                    break;
                case SPListTemplateType.GenericList:
                    newItemString = "item";
                    break;
                case SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary:
                    newItemString = "document";
                    break;
                default:
                    newItemString = "item";
                    break;
            }
            if (spView.ParentList.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
            {
                newItemString = "document";
            }
            // Add the CAML
            toolbarNode.InnerXml = @"<IfHasRights><RightsChoices><RightsGroup PermAddListItems=""required"" /></RightsChoices><Then><HTML><![CDATA[ <table width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 > <tr> <td colspan=""2"" class=""ms-partline""><IMG src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" width=1 height=1 alt=""""></td> </tr> <tr> <td class=""ms-addnew"" style=""padding-bottom: 3px""> <img src=""/_layouts/images/rect.gif"" alt="""">&nbsp;<a class=""ms-addnew"" ID=""idAddNewItem"" href=""]]></HTML><URL Cmd=""New"" /><HTML><![CDATA["" ONCLICK=""javascript:NewItem(']]></HTML><URL Cmd=""New"" /><HTML><![CDATA[', true);javascript:return false;"" target=""_self"">]]></HTML><HTML>Add new " + newItemString + @"</HTML><HTML><![CDATA[</a> </td> </tr> <tr><td><IMG src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" width=1 height=5 alt=""""></td></tr> </table>]]></HTML></Then></IfHasRights>";
        }
        spView.Update();
}
```

Comment: Did you try it on Sandbox Solution ??.. I have tried it but showing error on 'BindingFlags'.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the toolbar type.Here is simple code for you

Code Block
lMgr =OpenWebPartManager("Default.Aspx");

```
// Get web Part

wp = lMgr.WebParts[wp.ID] as WebPart;

ListViewWebPart lv = (ListViewWebPart)wp;

// Extract view

System.Reflection.PropertyInfo ViewProp = lv.GetType().GetProperty("View", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

SPView spView = ViewProp.GetValue(lv, null) as SPView;

// This forces a refresh of the views internal xml or the node's cild nodes are not populated

string txt = spView.SchemaXml;

System.Reflection.PropertyInfo NodeProp = spView.GetType().GetProperty("Node", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

XmlNode node = NodeProp.GetValue(spView, null) as XmlNode;

XmlNode tBarNode = node.SelectSingleNode("Toolbar");

if (tBarNode != null)

{

tBarNode.Attributes["Type"].Value = "None";

spView.Update();

}
```

Comment: Is 'lMgr' object of SPLimitedWebprtManager ?, if yes then it's not working on Sandbox Solution.And also 'BindingFlags' shows error.